# Export a layer from QGIS to Oracle DB

Tags: qgis, sql, export, import, oracle-spatial

I have a working connection to an Oracle database in QGIS (3.4). I am able to import and edit existing tables into my QGIS project out of the db. Unfortunately it is not possible to export any QGIS layer into the Oracle DB.
Trying to export to Oracle via drag and drop in the file browser, I get following error:

[image: Trying to Export to Oracle via drag and drop in]

> Failed to import some layers!
>   Creation of data source "DATEN"."TEST_POINTLAYER" failed: 
>   Oracle error: Could not insert metadata. 
>   SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY got CHAR 
>   Unable to execute statement 
>   Error: INSERT INTO mdsys.user_sdo_geom_metadata(table_name,column_name,srid,diminfo) 
>   VALUES (:a,:bb,:bc,:bd)

Another way to export layers to an oracle databse is the *DB Manager*. Trying to get my Testlayer into the db using the DB Manager causes a different error:
[image: Import Layer to Oracle db using DB Manager]

> Error 2 
>   Creation of data source "DATEN"."Test_Pointlayer" failed: 
>   Oracle error: Table creation failed. 
>   SQL: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier 
>   Unable to execute statement 
>   Error: CREATE TABLE "DATEN"."Test_Pointlayer"("" MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY)

So is there a way getting my testlayer into the oracle db without getting an error? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you also try to drag and drop it into the browser window just on the database?

Comment: Yes I already tried this. It returns the same error!

Comment: I encountered the same error of drag end drop also using db manager if I specify a import schema. It seem a problem related to the metadata table. 

Have you find any solution?

Comment: I'm also encountering this problem. I think it's connected to the 2 double quotes in before the `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` section in  `CREATE TABLE "DATEN"."Test_Pointlayer"("" MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY)`.